# Invalid css property gets removed in inline style

Tags: javascript, css, inline-styles

I have defined some inline-style in a element

```
<div id="box" style="-ms-grid-row:1; background-color: yellow;"></div>
```

and then with javascript I want to set a style.

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');
box.innerHTML += '<br>before: ' + box.getAttribute('style');
box.style.height = '100px';
box.innerHTML += '<br>after: ' + box.getAttribute('style');
```

and the output becomes:

```
before: -ms-grid-row:1; background-color: yellow;
after: background-color: yellow; height: 100px;
```

Test http://jsfiddle.net/P7eBN/

The browser removed -ms-grid-row property which I dont want it to do, because I am writing a plugin that reads inline-style with -ms-grid-row property so -ms-grid-row need to be preserved somehow. The same is it when using jQuery eg. `$(box).height(100)`

How can I in the best way allow users set height by style.height and still be able to read -ms-grid-row property afterwards somehow?

Comment: `-ms-` is IE only, I guess, so if the browser you're testing this on, does not understand such property, it might remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am writing a plugin that reads inline-style with -ms-grid-row property so -ms-grid-row need to be preserved somehow*. Sounds like the job for data attributes:

```
<div id="box" data-ms-grid-row="1" style="background-color: yellow;"></div>
```

And your plugin will read it as (cross-browser way)

```
box.getAttribute('data-ms-grid-row')
```

or for modern browsers:

```
box.dataset.msGridRow
```

Answer (score 2):

what about this?

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');
box.innerHTML += '<br>before: ' + box.getAttribute('style');
box.setAttribute('style', box.getAttribute('style') + ' height : 100px;');
box.innerHTML += '<br>after: ' + box.getAttribute('style');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write any CSS styles, it will be filtered and applied to the elements by the browser. Say, for eg., you write this CSS:

```
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
```

When you inspect in the Chrome Developer Tools, you will only see `-webkit-border-radius: 5px;` and others will not be applied.

**Solution**

Assuming you are serving the HTML to a decent version of browsers, so you can make use of the `data-` attributes. Send the styles to both this way:

```
style="border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;"
data-style="border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;"
```

And now you read the `data-style`, instead of `style`. Your final code will be somewhat like:

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');
box.innerHTML += '<br>before: ' + box.getAttribute('data-style');
box.setAttribute('style', box.getAttribute('style') + '; height : 100px');
box.innerHTML += '<br>after: ' + box.getAttribute('data-style');
```

Comment: While `data-` attributes might come to a rescue, use like this is more than overkill.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your page on Internet Explorer 9 and the property was preserved as expected. The -ms- prefix is ignored by browsers other than Internet Explorer. And hence you are not able to see it.

Comment: ah, yeah almost, I tested some more and added `display:-ms-grid` also. http://jsfiddle.net/tkPx2/ , that one gets removed in ie9. =/